# Attribute error- Django - list

Tags: python, django, meta

i´m starting with a simple example in Django, just testing things, and i´m getting an error.

This is the code i have in my view.py:

```
def index(request):
    file = open("wappApp/talk.txt", encoding="UTF-8")
    data = file.read()
    file.close()

    dates = search_date(data)

    return render(dates, 'wappApp/index.html')
```

dates is a list of dates.

And in my template i´m doing this:

```
<ul>
    {% for days in dates %}
        <li><a>{{ days }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But there is something i am not seing for being pretty new in django.

This is the error: 
    'list' object has no attribute 'META'

Any help will be really appreciatted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#render), render receives the param `request` as first argument and you are giving a 'list' instead. try this:

```
return render(request, 'wappApp/index.html', dates)
```

Keep in mind that `dates` is the context, it should be a `dict` not a `list`. In case you have it as a list, try this:

```
return render(request, 'wappApp/index.html', context={'dates': dates})
```

Update:

By the error you mention before, I can see that `dates` is a list, so by doing this:

```
{'dates': dates}
```

I create a dict with a key whose value is `dates`. So in template you'll be able to do:

```
{{ dates }}
```

and print the entire list to work with it.

Comment: Perfect sir. Thanks for the help. Can u develop more on this: context={'dates': dates}? Please. I´m waiting to mark it as correct